# Bash/Awk Sorting of files

Tags: shell, awk, files

I have multiple files in one directory minority with different formatting. I wish to separate those with specified format from those without. There's over 500 files which makes it time-consuming to do manually, so I figured some form of bash approach would be best.

Example of directory,

```
hello.txt
example.txt
world.txt
...
```

Example of desired format,

```
Hello \t World \t Hi
```

What I wish to do is move and/or copy those with the desired format to a separate folder.

A conditional approach would be something along the lines of:

```
awk -F"\t" {' $1 ~ "[a-zA-Z] && $2 ~ "[a-zA-Z]" && $3 ~ "[a-zA-Z]" && NF < 5}
```

so in that approach

```
$1 contains alpha
$2 contains alpha
$3 contains alpha
and the number of delimiters are below 5 ( incase )
```

that would work for a single file with minimal tweaks, but I need it to process each file within the directory and also to slow down the processing of each line being checked per file, the check could be set to line 1 or line 2 etc.

Comment: Do you want all the lines of the files to match those conditions? Or for the files to have at least one line that matches those conditions? Or do you care only for the first line?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas atleast one line so as stated at the bottom, you could choose to just check a specified line, ie line 10 or simply check the entire file for that line and break/stop check if condition is true

Comment: Note that `NF < 5` means the number of fields is strictly less than 5, which means a number of separators strictly less than 4. As you want the first 3 fields to have a letter, that suggests you want either 3 or 4 fields, is that right?

Comment: do you want fields $1, $2, and $3 to contain **only** alpha characters?   or are other characters allowed in those fields as long as there is at least one alpha char?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU `awk` and `mv` you could do:

```bash
gawk -F'\t' -v ORS='\0' '
  NF < 5 && $1 ~ /[[:alpha:]]/ && $2 ~ /[[:alpha:]]/ && $3 ~ /[[:alpha:]]/ {
    print FILENAME; nextfile
  }' ./*.txt | xargs -r0 mv -t destination-directory
```

Which would move to `destination-directory` the (non-hidden) files whose name ends in `.txt` and contain at least one line with fewer than 5 fields (fewer than 4 delimiters) and whose first 3 fields contain at least one alphabetic character.

That could also be done with GNU `grep` and `mv` with:

```bash
grep -lZxP '([^\t]*[[:alpha:]][^\t]*)\t(?1)\t(?1)(\t[^\t]*)?' ./*.txt |
  xargs -r0 mv -t destination-directory
```

Comment: Does this check very line or just the 1 line?

Comment: @user369555, it looks until it finds a matching line. Then it prints the filename and proceeds to the next file. If you want it to give up searching after the third line, you can add a `FNR == 3 {nextfile}` statement.

Comment: Thanks this works! really appreciate your time & support.

Comment: `NF>2 && NF<5 && $1$2$3 ~ /^[[:alpha:]]+$/` is shorter/simpler and a lot less typing.  This is assuming the OP wants $1, $2, and $3 to contain **only** alpha characters...which they haven't explicitly states, but seems likely.

Comment: @cas that would match on `x\t\t` and not `a1\tb-c\td e` which goes against the OP's stated requirements. That the OP wants to match text as opposed to numbers is equally likely.

Comment: if the field sep is \t, the NF>2 prevents it from matching that....must be at least three fields but less than 5, and the first three must be nothing but [:alpha:].   if the space characters at the end of each field are meant to be there, then use `/^([[:alpha:]] ){3,}$/`.  or ` *` if they're optional for each field. or perhaps use `-F' \t'`

Comment: @cas, `x\t\t` has 3 fields, 2 of which are empty.

Comment: and fields 2 & 3 won't match [[:alpha:]]

Comment: The point of my comment was that it's worth looking for ways to avoid repeating yourself, because repetition is an opportunity for error to creep in.   For most input data, there can be found a combination of field separator and regular expression that can reduce N field comparisons against the same regex down to 1 comparison by simple concatenation of the N fields.

Comment: For `x\t\t`, `$1$2$3` is `x` which matches `/^[[:alpha:]]+$/`. IOW, that's not a valid optimisation.

Comment: yes, and i then provided other regexps / field separators that would work.  Again, my point was not to quibble about one particular regexp.  as i said, it was about minimising repetition.